Is it possible for there to be three points in space which are not in the same plane?
Is it possible for there to be three points in space which are not in the same
plane?
The answer is given as no.
But you could have three points, each one on a separate plane that are all parallel to each other, like adjacent walls. So I'm correct and the book is wrong?

There's a lot more planes to consider than the ones parallel to your chosen walls. Think about it this way. There are infinitely many planes that contain two of the points, rotated by different amounts with respect to the axis through the two points. As you rotate a plane around this axis, at some point you'll hit the third point, and then you're done.

I see where I made a mistake. The adjacent walls are indeed separate planes. But you can still make one unique plane that connects the three points despite them each being on adjacent parallel planes. So yes the answer is indeed no.

How about $${\rho_1\vec a+\rho_2\vec b+\rho_3\vec c\mid\rho_1+\rho_2+\rho_3=1}$$? It contains the points $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ and is (subset of) a plane.

What do you think about two points?

But isn't there a plane passing through those three points? You are assuming that only one plane passes through a point, which is clearly not true.

Why is it not true though? The question only asks if three points in space can be on separate planes, and I showed that it's possible.

Well your question is whether there exist three points in space which are not in the same plane, thus if you can find atleast one plane which passes through any three points you have refuted the claim of the question. This you can certainly do.

@ronaldchristenkkson sounds like an a question of English interpretation to me. My interpretation of whether "there exist three points in space which are not in the same plane," is do "there exist three points that are not contained in any plane."

I just saw your reply in chat. You did not ping me (using "@[username]") so I did not get notified. That Basic Math chat-room is indeed for basic mathematics (i.e. up to the undergraduate level). I do not know what you mean by "dead"; it is in regular use, but trolls are not welcome. Do you still want access to the "dead" chat-room? (Ping me when you reply.)

@user21820 Yes I would still want access to the chat room. Apparently it's very unlike a discord server,  which is really good. (Also sorry for my late response I was busy.)

@Zaid: I have granted you access. You are welcome to post any mathematical inquiry there. But please refrain from making comments such as "dead", as it is typical of trolls, which have in the past caused a lot of trouble for all the other participants in my chat-rooms, and so the moderators told me to change it to gallery mode precisely to keep trolls out.

@user21820 Thank you. I'm sorry for calling it "dead", as you can see I'm new to the site and am not familiar with the rate at which messages are sent back and forth here.

@Zaid: No problem! Try posting a message in that room just to make sure you can? See you there! =)

This can be easily proved by pigeon hole theorem but I forget how it was used here,but still for two points in space will always from a straight line. Similarly for three points in space, will form a triangle, we can say this because let Points A,B,C in the space then, from previous observation, AB is a straight line so is BC and so is CA, then it will be a triangle and a triangle exists in one plane

I can’t understand, if you forgot how to use this theorem, who will believe your written answer is correct.

I tried to say that, it can be done by pigeon hole theroem but I forgot it. So i proved it in an another way

The answer is indeed no.
Think about it like this, consider points $A,B,C$. Then we form two vectors connecting $A$ to $B$, say $AB$, and $A$ to $C$, denote as $AC$. Then a plane can be formed by the linear combination of $AB$ and $AC$, and it includes all the three points.

You may define a plane by three points(1), that is why three points are in the plane they define -- no matter in how many other planes each of the points is also.
(1) -- if by chance not colinear (on the same line)
